# Add dictionary for spellchecking

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, textarea

Currently, if an element specifies a language, and the user has no dictionary installed for that language, spell check is disabled by default

For example, this will work fine on a computer with an English dictionary installed (every computer whose OS language is set to English)

```
<textarea lang="en"></textarea>
```

However, unless you have a Ukrainian dictionary installed, this code will disable spellcheck in the `div`

```
<textarea lang="uk"></textarea>
```

Is there any way to "import" a Ukrainian dictionary onto a HTML page? If not, what other options are there for spellchecking? (Assuming the user doesn't have the dictionary installed)